# Android: app crashes on starting new activity

Tags: android, crash, textview

Basicaly, I want to start an activity that prints out the input string and an image under.

In activity_display_message.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView 
            android:text="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/serious" />    


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code in OnCreate():

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);  
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    // Create the text view

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    //textView.setTextSize(20);

    textView.setText(message);
    // Set the text view as the activity layout   


    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

EDIT: Not sure how to get the stack trace, but I just found these lines in Catlog:

```
07-05 12:26:53.677: E/AppsCustomizePagedView(611): Widget ComponentInfo{com.th.android.widget.gTabsimiClock/com.th.android.widget.gTabsimiClock.GTabsimiClock5x1} can not fit on this device (736, 144)
07-05 12:26:53.692: E/AppsCustomizePagedView(611): Widget ComponentInfo{at.abraxas.powerwidget.free/at.abraxas.powerwidget.free.SettingsAppWidgetProvider_5} can not fit on this device (760, 80)
07-05 12:26:57.958: E/AudioCache(131): Error 1, -1004 occurred
07-05 12:26:58.146: E/AudioCache(131): Error 1, -1004 occurred
07-05 12:26:58.630: E/AudioCache(131): Error 1, -1004 occurred
07-05 12:27:07.833: E/AudioCache(131): Heap size overflow! req size 1052672, max size: 1048576
```

Is this the stack trace?

```
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474): STACKTRACE
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:38)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-05 12:41:10.058: E/TAG(22474):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Stack trace when crashes at runtime: (the one above was obtained by doing try / catch)

```
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:38)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-05 12:52:24.386: E/AndroidRuntime(25496):    ... 11 more
```

message is not null. When I change OnCreate to below, the message is printed: (but of course, not the image)

```
// Create the text view

//TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(20);

textView.setText(message);
setContentView(textView);
```

ANSWER: Found the mistake: android:text="@+id/textView" . Should be android:id, not android:text ...

But thank you all for your help. You guys have made the android programming experience for beginners like me a lot better.

Comment: Whenever there is a crash, always include the logcat, it means we can pinpoint the error

Comment: post the stack trace `String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE)` message might be null

Comment: Paste the LogCat and the code where you're sending your data to this Activity

Comment: What reveals the stack trace?

Comment: @Raghunandan I think I found it. Posted above.

Comment: @SquallLeonhart what' on line 38  `DisplayMessageActivity.java`

Comment: textView.setText(message);

Comment: @SquallLeonhart message seems to be null. check if message is null or not. Also the key may not be matching. use the same key. the one used in MainActivity.

Comment: I dont think it's null. see the end of the original post.

Comment: @SquallLeonhart before the update it looked like message was null since textview is initialized textview could not be null. so the on line 38 it had to be messsge null. The only explanation can be textview could be null (initialization) failed which to me looks unlikely.

Comment: how come in this case, I can call setContent AFTER initializing text view and setText?

Comment: @SquallLeonhart check my answer. You are using activity context to initialize textview. While had textview in xml and you can `findViewById` of the current viewhierarchy set to the activity.

Comment: @Raghunandan Makes sense. Now, I change it back to the original code. Right before I do setText, I use Log.v to pritn out the message and it is printed perfectly fine in catlog.

Comment: @Raghunandan : **"...before the update it looked like message was null..."** - For your future reference, calling `setText(CharSequence text)` with a `null` argument will not cause NPE as the method does a check for `null` before attempting to set the text. If it is `null` then it will be initialised to `""`.

Comment: @Squonk: so its not the message that is null. it's the textView?

Comment: @Squonk you are right . i just checked the source code @ http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Candroid.widget.TextView.BufferType%29. i will edit my answer by posting the same.

Comment: Actually, I found the mistake. It's really embarassing. See the original post.

Comment: @SquallLeonhart : **"so its not the message that is null. it's the textView?"** - Correct. The only way that `textView.setText(message);`  can possibly throw NPE is if `textView` is `null`. This can be caused either by trying to use `findViewById(...)` before views have been created OR specifying the wrong (or an invalid) `R.id` OR in some cases if the `R.java` file is corrupt. In the latter case, using Project -> Clean should fix things.

Comment: @SquallLeonhart : **"ANSWER: Found the mistake:..."** - LOL, I looked at your code several times over and didn't spot that.

Comment: @Squonk is there no lint warning about missing id for a view in your layout xml.

Comment: @Raghunandan I set up eclipse to ignore lint warnings since eclipse gives me too many. I guess I learned my lesson...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the content to the activity first.

You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. Since you have not set the content to the activity you will get `NullPointerException` if you try to initialize views.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message); 
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setTextSize(20);
textView.setText(message);
....
}
```

Edit:

As Squonk commented `setText(CharSequence text)` checks for null

From

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Candroid.widget.TextView.BufferType%29

The implementation looks like

```
3561    private void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type,
3562                         boolean notifyBefore, int oldlen) {
3563        if (text == null) { // checking for null
3564            text = ""; 
3565        }   
        .....
```

So line 38 is `textView.setText(message)` which causes NPE. So the textView is not initialized which causes NPE.

Further to the update and Squonk comment

`textview` can be null bcoz of  specifying the wrong (or an invalid) `R.id` OR in some cases if the `R.java` file is corrupt. In the latter case, using Project -> Clean should fix things.

Also this

```
android:text="@+id/textView" // this is actually setting text to textview.
```

You were missing

```
android:id="@+id/textView" // textview id attribute missing
```

SO when you try to initialize

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
// there is no textview with id  textView which caused NPE
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you declare your activity in the manifest file? please check that too.

Comment: yes i did. at first i was just displaying the image and it worked

Comment: retrieve your data from previous activity using : Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); then retrieve it by calling extras.getString("key")..try this edit

Comment: @NirajAdhikari : That will make no differnce - the `getStringExtra(...)` method is perfectly acceptable. There is no need to use `getExtras()` to get the `Bundle` first.

Answer (score 1):

setContentView should be called before creating Imageview object.

Answer (score 0):

Put setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);  line at the top of onCreate method.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message); 

    ......
    rest code

    }
```

Comment: Posted in the original post.

Comment: @Mufazzal your oncreate does not have bundle param